# DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Tags: sql-server, delete, referential-integrity

My situation looks like this:

Table STOCK_ARTICLES:

```
ID *[PK]*
OTHER_DB_ID
ITEM_NAME
```

Table LOCATION:

```
ID *[PK]*
LOCATION_NAME
```

Table WORK_PLACE:

```
ID *[PK]*
WORKPLACE_NAME
```

Table INVENTORY_ITEMS:

```
ID *[PK]*
ITEM_NAME
STOCK_ARTICLE *[FK]*
LOCATION *[FK]*
WORK_PLACE *[FK]*
```

The 3 FKs in INVENTORY_ITEMS reference the "ID" columns in the respective other tables, obviously.

The relevant tables here are STOCK_ARTICLE and INVENTORY_ITEMS.

Now there is a SQL job consisting of several steps (SQL scripts) that "synchronizes" the database mentioned above with *another* database (OTHER_DB). One of the steps inside this job is for "cleanup". It deletes all records from STOCK_ITEMS where there's no corresponding record in the other database with the same ID.
It looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM STOCK_ARTICLES
 WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT OTHER_DB_ID FROM
     [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[OtherTable] AS other
               WHERE other.ObjectID = STOCK_ARTICLES.OTHER_DB_ID)
```

But this step always fails with:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_INVENTORY_ITEMS_STOCK_ARTICLES". The conflict occurred in database
>   "FIRST_DB", table "dbo.INVENTORY_ITEMS", column 'STOCK_ARTICLES'.
>   [SQLSTATE 23000] (Error 547)  The statement has been terminated.
>   [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  The step failed.

So the problem is that it can't delete records from STOCK_ARTICLES when they are referenced by INVENTORY_ITEMS.
But this cleanup needs to work.
Which means that I probably have to extend the cleanup script so that it first identifies the records that should be deleted from STOCK_ITEMS, but can't because the corresponding ID is referenced from inside INVENTORY_ITEMS.
Then it should first delete those records inside INVENTORY_ITEMS, and after that delete the records inside STOCK_ARTICLES.
Am I right?
How would the SQL code look like then?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

That is the whole point of foreign key constraints: they stop you deleting data that is referred to elsewhere in order to maintain referential integrity.

There are two options:

1. Delete the rows from `INVENTORY_ITEMS` first, *then* the rows from `STOCK_ARTICLES`.
2. Use `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the in the key definition.

**1: Deleting In Correct Order**

The most efficient way to do this varies depending on the complexity of the query that decides which rows to delete. A general pattern might be:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET XACT_ABORT ON
DELETE INVENTORY_ITEMS WHERE STOCK_ARTICLE IN (<select statement that returns stock_article.id for the rows you are about to delete>)
DELETE STOCK_ARTICLES WHERE <the rest of your current delete statement>
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

This is fine for simple queries or for deleting a single stock item, but given your delete statement contains a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause nesting that within `WHERE IN` might produce a very inefficient plan so test with a realistic data set size and rearrange the query if needed.

Also note the transaction statements: you want to make sure both the deletes complete or neither of them do. If the operation is already happening within a transaction you will obviously need to alter this to match your current transaction and error handling process.

**2: Use `ON DELETE CASCADE`**

If you add the cascade option to your foreign key then SQL Server will automatically do this for you, removing rows from `INVENTORY_ITEMS` to satisfy the constraint that nothing should refer to the rows you are deleting. Just add `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the FK definition like so:

```
ALTER TABLE <child_table> WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT <fk_name> FOREIGN KEY(<column(s)>)
REFERENCES <parent_table> (<column(s)>)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

An advantage here is that the delete is one atomic statement reducing (though, as usual, not 100% removing) the need to worry about transaction and lock settings. The cascade can even operate over multiple parent/child/grand-child/... levels *if* there is only one path between parent and all the descendants (search for "multiple cascade paths" for examples of where this might not work).

*NOTE: I, and many others, consider cascaded deletes to be dangerous so if you use this option be very careful to properly document it in your database design so you and other developers don't trip over the danger later*. I avoid cascading deletes wherever possible for this reason.

A common problem caused with cascaded deletes is when someone updates data by dropping and recreating rows instead of using `UPDATE` or `MERGE`. This is often seen where "update the rows that already exist, insert those that don't" (sometimes called an UPSERT operation) is needed and people unaware of the `MERGE` statement find it easier to do:

```
DELETE <all rows that match IDs in the new data>
INSERT <all rows from the new data>
```

than

```
-- updates
UPDATE target 
SET    <col1> = source.<col1>
  ,    <col2> = source.<col2>
       ...
  ,    <colN> = source.<colN>
FROM   <target_table> AS target JOIN <source_table_or_view_or_statement> AS source ON source.ID = target.ID
-- inserts
INSERT  <target_table>
SELECT  *
FROM    <source_table_or_other> AS source
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        <target_table> AS target
        ON target.ID = source.ID
WHERE   target.ID IS NULL
```

The problem here is that the delete statement will cascade to child rows, and the insert statement won't recreate them, so while updating the parent table you accidentally lose data from the child table(s).

**Summary**

Yes, you have to delete the child rows first.

There is another option: `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

*But `ON DELETE CASCADE` can be dangerous*, so use with care.

Side note: use `MERGE` (or `UPDATE`-and-`INSERT` where `MERGE` is not available) when you need an `UPSERT` operation, *not* `DELETE`-then-replace-with-`INSERT` to avoid falling into traps laid by other people using `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get IDs to delete only once, store them in temporary table and use to delete operations. Then you have better control what are you deleting.

This operation shouldn't fail:

```
SELECT sa.ID INTO #StockToDelete
FROM STOCK_ARTICLES sa
LEFT JOIN [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[OtherTable] other ON other.ObjectID = sa.OTHER_DB_ID
WHERE other.ObjectID IS NULL

DELETE ii
FROM INVENTORY_ITEMS ii
JOIN #StockToDelete std ON ii.STOCK_ARTICLE = std.ID

DELETE sa
FROM STOCK_ARTICLES sa
JOIN #StockToDelete std ON sa.ID = std.ID
```

Comment: Though if deleting large numbers of STOCK_ARTICLES rows this is likely to perform worse than the other options because of building the temp table (for small numbers of rows the difference is unlikely to be significant). Also take care to use appropriate transaction directives to ensure that the three statements are executed as an atomic unit if concurrent access is not impossible, otherwise you could see errors as new `INVENTORY_ITEMS` being added between the two `DELETE`s.

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue, and I was able to resolve it.  Here is my situation:

In my case, I have a database used for reporting an analytics (MYTARGET_DB), which pulls from a source system (MYSOURCE_DB).  Some of the 'MYTARGET_DB' tables are unique to that system, and data is created & managed there; Most of the tables are from 'MYSOURCE_DB' and there is a job that deletes/ inserts the data into 'MYTARGET_DB' from 'MYSOURCE_DB'.

One of the lookup tables [PRODUCT] is from the SOURCE, and there is a data table [InventoryOutsourced] stored in the TARGET.  There is referential integrity designed into the tables.  So when I try to run the delete/insert I get this message.

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure uspJobInsertAllTables_AM, Line 249
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_InventoryOutsourced_Product". The conflict occurred in database "ProductionPlanning", table "dbo.InventoryOutsourced", column 'ProdCode'.
```

The workaround I created is to insert data into [@tempTable] table variable from [InventoryOutsourced], delete data in [InventoryOutsourced], run the synch jobs, insert into [InventoryOutsourced] from [@tempTable].  This keeps the integrity in place, and the unique data collection is also retained.  Which is the best of both worlds.  Hope this helps.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION InsertAllTables_AM

        DECLARE
        @BatchRunTime datetime = getdate(),
        @InsertBatchId bigint
            select @InsertBatchId = max(IsNull(batchid,0)) + 1 from JobRunStatistic 

        --<DataCaptureTmp/> Capture the data tables unique to this database, before deleting source system reference tables
            --[InventoryOutsourced]
            DECLARE @tmpInventoryOutsourced as table (
                [ProdCode]      VARCHAR (12)    NOT NULL,
                [WhseCode]      VARCHAR (4)     NOT NULL,
                [Cases]          NUMERIC (8)     NOT NULL,
                [Weight]         NUMERIC (10, 2) NOT NULL,
                [Date] DATE NOT NULL, 
                [SourcedFrom] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
                [User] NCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
                [ModifiedDatetime] DATETIME NOT NULL
                )

            INSERT INTO @tmpInventoryOutsourced (
                [ProdCode]
               ,[WhseCode]
               ,[Cases]
               ,[Weight]
               ,[Date]
               ,[SourcedFrom]
               ,[User]
               ,[ModifiedDatetime]
               )
            SELECT 
                [ProdCode]
                ,[WhseCode]
                ,[Cases]
                ,[Weight]
                ,[Date]
                ,[SourcedFrom]
                ,[User]
                ,[ModifiedDatetime]
            FROM [dbo].[InventoryOutsourced]

            DELETE FROM [InventoryOutsourced]
        --</DataCaptureTmp> 

... Delete Processes
... Delete Processes    

        --<DataCaptureInsert/> Capture the data tables unique to this database, before deleting source system reference tables
            --[InventoryOutsourced]
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[InventoryOutsourced] (
                [ProdCode]
               ,[WhseCode]
               ,[Cases]
               ,[Weight]
               ,[Date]
               ,[SourcedFrom]
               ,[User]
               ,[ModifiedDatetime]
               )
            SELECT 
                [ProdCode]
                ,[WhseCode]
                ,[Cases]
                ,[Weight]
                ,[Date]
                ,[SourcedFrom]
                ,[User]
                ,[ModifiedDatetime]
            FROM @tmpInventoryOutsourced
            --</DataCaptureInsert> 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION InsertAllTables_AM
END TRY
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully tested, but something like this should work.

```
--cte of Stock Articles to be deleted
WITH StockArticlesToBeDeleted AS
(
SELECT ID FROM STOCK_ARTICLES
 WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT OTHER_DB_ID FROM
     [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[OtherTable] AS other
               WHERE other.ObjectID = STOCK_ARTICLES.OTHER_DB_ID)
)
--delete from INVENTORY_ITEMS where we have a match on deleted STOCK_ARTICLE
DELETE a FROM INVENTORY_ITEMS a join
StockArticlesToBeDeleted b on
    b.ID = a.STOCK_ARTICLE;

--now, delete from STOCK_ARTICLES
DELETE FROM STOCK_ARTICLES
 WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT OTHER_DB_ID FROM
     [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[OtherTable] AS other
               WHERE other.ObjectID = STOCK_ARTICLES.OTHER_DB_ID);
```